# Is there an ARM template solution for binding a Logic App to an OMS workspace?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-rm-template, azure-log-analytics

As of this moment the Logic app connector for OMS is in preview, so I may just be too early with this inquiry. I'm looking to deploy a number of Logic Apps and would like to configure all of them to pump analytics into the same OMS workspace which our operations team will be monitoring.

I [found a great script to link resources in an Azure subscription to an OMS workspace](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/msoms/2017/01/17/enable-azure-resource-metrics-logging-using-powershell/), but I was hoping to find a way to accomplish this using an ARM template. Binding a logic app to a workspace doesn't impact the generated 'Automation Script' for the resource group in the portal.

Is anyone in the know?

Comment: You can use the following template as your basis: https://gallery.azure.com/artifact/20161101/Microsoft.EmptyWorkflow.1.0.9/DeploymentTemplates/LogicApp_ConsumptionPlan_OmsWorkspaceWithSolution.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following template is a good basis for getting started
https://gallery.azure.com/artifact/20161101/Microsoft.EmptyWorkflow.1.0.9/DeploymentTemplates/LogicApp_ConsumptionPlan_OmsWorkspaceWithSolution.json

(This template is used by the create resource blade in the Azure portal)